# Excel - numeric wildcard to aid grouping of values?

Tags: excel, grouping, wildcard, sumifs

I'm using `SUMIFS` in Excel to add values on the basis of a site name. Currently, I'm using a `*` wildcard to establish a generic site name so that similar site names are considered together (e.g. `London&'*'` to group together `"London 1"` and `"London 2"`). My problem is that when the site names are too similar, as below:

```
"London 1"
"London 2"
"London Oxford St 1"
"London Oxford St 2"
"London Hammersmith"
```

then `London&'*'` considers all of the above site names together, instead of grouping the ones that I want to group together (i.e. the ones where the site name is followed by a numeric value; `"London 1"` and `"London 2"`).

**Is there a way of considering only numeric values for the wildcard instead of any text?**

Comment: Maybe add a condition to your SUMIFS for the length of the site using LEN()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `London 1` and `London 2` you can use the question mark `?` wildcard

`London ?`

It refers to a single character, rather than any number of characters - which is what the asterisk gives you

Note that it won't give you anything greater than `London 9`. For `London 10` to `London 99` you would need to have `London ??` as your criteria

Also note that I didn't use the ampersand `&`. `"London"&"*"` is the same as `"London*"`

---

Comment: Happy to help, if this answered your question please accept the answer by clicking the tick mark to the left of this answer

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this if you definitely wanted ones ending in a number to be grouped (works for a single digit)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND("London "&{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A2:A10))*B2:B10)
```

where the site names are in column A and the values in column B.

EDIT

This is actually equivalent to "*London [0-9]*" so "Baker Street " would also find Sherlock Holmes Baker Street 221B.

This is equivalent to "London [0-9]"

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10="London "&{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0})*B2:B10)
```